# Updating variables in addcontentview - android

Tags: android, opengl-es, hud

I have been developing a game with opengles for android and have a glsurfaceview displayed. I also have a textview displayed over this by using

```
addContentView(mytextview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
```

mytextview contains a string which is made up of a string plus the parsed value of an int. eg something like

```
 mytextview = new TextView(this);
 mytextview.setText("Score: " + Integer.toString(score) );
```

The textview and the integer value display but
My question is how do I update this when the integer value changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to call `mytextview.setText("Score: " + Integer.toString(score) );`
 every time the score changes.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can change the position of the text? I have tried different methods such as offsetleftandright().

Comment: you can call `setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)` on the textView, where `left,top,right,bottom` are integers.